# Make array from another array's spacial elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have such array:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [meta_id] => 24674
            [post_id] => 798
            [meta_key] =>pr_no
            [meta_value] => 00649
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [meta_id] => 24653
            [post_id] => 796
            [meta_key] => pr_no
            [meta_value] => 00645
        )
etc.
```

How can I make an array, that will contain only meta_values. Like:

```
Array(0=>00649, 1=>00645, 2+>00644)
```

Comment: I can do it so:
**$num_rows = sizeof($array);
   for ($i = 0; $i<$num_rows; $i++)
   {
    echo $array[$i]['meta_value']."</br>";
   }** But maybe there are better ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
$meta_values = array();

foreach($arrays AS $array){
  foreach($array AS $key => $value) {
    if($key == "meta_value"){
      array_push($meta_values, $value);
    }
  }       
}
```

This function will loop through the existing array, looking for any `meta_value` keys. When it finds one, it will push the value of that key into a new array.

Edit:

Missed the 2D array, meaning you'd have to do a nested-foreach.

Comment: Waitaminute, it is a 2D array!

Comment: Wellithink, the inner loop could be written as `$meta_values[] = $array['meta_value']  ;`-)

Comment: Yes it can, but depending on the size of the array, you would use one or the other. `array_push` is great for large arrays, while `$meta_values = array($value)` would be great for small ones.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help, arrays can be confusing at first.

Comment: yeah, I am new in PHP and help is appreciated a lot :))

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PHP >= 5.5.0 there's the extra useful [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function to do just that!

```
 $newArray = array_column($array, 'meta_id');
```

If you're stuck with an older version of PHP, check out the comments in the link above for workarounds.